# Using request.on() for GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

When dealing with `GET` requests, should I be using `request.on()`?

For instance, in my `main.js`,

```
var http = require('http');
var dispatcher = require('./public/javascript/dispatcher.js');
var serverPort = 8124;
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  dispatcher.deal(request, response);
}).listen(serverPort);
```

and in `dispatcher.js`, I have

```
module.exports = {

    deal: function(request, response) {
        if(request.method === "GET") {  // WITHIN THIS BLOCK
            var get = require('./get.js');
            // Pass data to the appropriate function
            get.do(request, response);
        } else if(request.method === "POST") { 
            var qs = require('querystring');
            var requestBody = '';

            request.on('data', function(data) {
                requestBody += data;
            });

            request.on('end', function() {
                var formData = qs.parse(requestBody);
                var post = require('./post.js');

                // Pass data to the appropriate function
                post.doing(request, response, formData);
            });
        }
    } // End deal
} // End exports
```

So to expand on my initial question and the code I've posted, the program works fine without the `request.on()`. My *guess* is that since there's no data to wait for from a `GET` request, there's no need for a `require.on('end', ...)`. Any clarifications, recommendations, or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You should restructure your code so that you only have a single `request.on` data and end handler, then have it branch out from there to handle request types separately.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there any necessity for having the `GET` request inside the `request.on(end)`?